# Can't start mongodb server

Tags: mongodb

I just installed mongodb server using homebrew as described [here](https://treehouse.github.io/installation-guides/mac/mongo-mac.html)

When I run `mongod` to start the server, I get: 
[image]

What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**

`mongo -version` gives me: 

`MongoDB shell version v4.0.0
git version: 3b07af3d4f471ae89e8186d33bbb1d5259597d51
allocator: system
modules: none
build environment:
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64`

Comment: Looks like your /data/db is not empty . Since your are trying to start mongod 4.0 but the data was created with 3.6 hence its getting terminated . Try running the mongod --dbpath ANYNEWFOLDERPATH

Comment: Yeah I emptied the /data/db directory and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your /data/db is not empty . Since your are trying to start mongod 4.0 but the data was created with 3.6 hence its getting terminated . Try running with

---

> mongod --dbpath ANYNWFOLDERPATH –

---